# Improve performance that uses isnull in a where clause

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

There is a report whose query is using isnull in the where clause and it's causing some performance issues. 
Here is a very simplified example. 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79759/11

The query is using a multi-valued parameter, usually just returning one or two values. (I've tried to replicate the SSRS multi-value param using a table variable in sqlfiddle)

```
select 
  isnull(descrL,descr) as division,
  product
from Upper
left join Lower on product = productL
where isnull(DescrL,Descr) in (@params)
```

There is an Upper division that has all the products. Some of the products exist on a child  division. If it exists in the lower division, that is the division that should be shown.

The company parameter can accept the upper division, lower division, or both.

Any ideas on how the query can be changed for better performance?

Comment: does the reported product always have to come from the Upper table, even when the description match is found in Lower?

Comment: Yes, the two division are related. There is information only in the upper table pertaining to that product.

Comment: How many records in the two tables?

Comment: Is the `Lower.DescrL` column nullable or not?

Comment: @RThomas about 50,000 in each.
ypercube No. Although there may not be a link between upper and lower (hence the left join).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  descrL as division, product
from Lower 
where DescrL like @params + '%'
union
Select descr, product
from Upper
where Descr like @params = '%'
```

This would be very performant.  If the match is found in the top select, it should be suppressed in the bottom select since it's a union instead of a union all.  Notice the like instead of in.  If you do an in there is just no way to use an index on DescrL or Descr to find the results.  If you do a like, indexes are used fine.  You may have to adjust your application logic to make that work.

If you can't do that, then there is this solution.  You'll have to add fn_split to your db.  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496058(v=sql.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496058%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

```
    select  descrL as division, product
    from Lower l 
    join dbo.fn_Split(@params, ',') p1
        on l.DescrL = p1.value
    union
    Select descr, product
    from Upper u 
    join dbo.fn_Split(@params, ',') p2
        on u.Descr = p2.value
```

If you really want to eke out the very last bit of performance you can declare a table variable and only run the fn_split once in order to populate the table variable, and then make the two joins be to the table variable.  So here you are also taking advantage of the index on the columns, which is the main thing you need to make the query faster.  Always do 'include actual execution plan' in sql server when you run it, and look at the results and make sure you're seeing index seeks instead of table scans.

EDIT: I went over to your sqlfiddle link.  Didn't see it earlier.  This works.  The union by itself won't suppress dupes, since you are also selecting the division, sorry.  So you have to use a not in, or as I prefer, a left outer where null.

```
select descrL as division, productL as product
    from Lower l 
    join @params p1
        on l.DescrL = p1.division
    union
    Select u.descr, u.product
    from Upper u 
    join @params p2
        on u.Descr = p2.division
    left join (select productL as product
                from Lower l2 
               join @params p3
                 on l2.DescrL = p3.division) sub1
     on u.product = sub1.product
        where sub1.product is null
order by 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but would a cte work in your situation?

```
;with BothDivs as
(
  select 
  isnull(descrL,descr) as division,
  product
  from Upper
  left join Lower on product = productL
)
select division, product
from BothDivs
where division in (@params)
```